# Displaying image from the database in MVC

Tags: c#, html, image, base64, binary-data

I have a field (the type is varbinary) in my database that respresent an image. I would to read this image and display it in my view. i read from database using ADO.

in my data service i have (this is part of private web api project):

```cs
img= (byte []) reader["Image"];
```

i convert varbinary to array of byte
the my view is basically :

```html
<img src="data:image/tiff;base64, @Model.ImageSource" />
```

but in my controller im not able to create a base64 string to assign in view to img tag. 
Another problem can be that image is stored as tiff format.

I have tried in controller to do (this is in another mvc project that recall web api):

```cs
// call my service that return me image
 var result = await client.GetAsync("ImagesController/GetImageBytes/" + id);

// ImageSource is a property of my viewmodel
ImageSource=Convert.ToBase64String(result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
// or
  ImageSource= Convert.ToBase64String(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Byte[]>(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result))
// or 
 ImageSource= Convert.ToBase64String(result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result)
```

but despite hundreds of attempts (really) Im not able to visualize anything. My view show image placeholder only.

Someone can help me?

Comment: what is `result` in this code? What's the content of `image.src`? What has JSON got to do with anything?? Not sure what that attempt was about. Anyway my point is since we have no idea what your variables contain it's quite hard to say why things didn't work. If you have a variable which contains a byte array, which itself contains data taken from the varbinary field in your database, then you should be able to pass that to the `Convert.ToBase64String()` method and it'll work no problem. You seem to have defined `img` as the byte array, but then you never use it in your later code.

Comment: I'd have expected that `ImageSource = Convert.ToBase64String(img);` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I have edited my code for better understanding

Comment: What is `client`? What type of object does it return? Probably not a byte array by default I'd guess. And...is this Imagescontroller part of your same project? If so then why on earth are you calling it via a HTTP request? Instead just run the same background method as that controller action calls and get the data that way...much more efficient.

Comment: client is httpclient from which I call the web service

Comment: Ok. So Can you answer my question about why you don't just fetch the data directly, instead of invoking a controller which appears to be part of the same project? That's just a bizarre thing to do.

Comment: I have a private web api project that I recall from the mvc project.
I updated the question to clarify

Comment: Ok. Back to the issue. When your page loads, you say you see only the placeholder. Can you give more information? Inspect your image element with the browser's Inspect tool (right-click the image and click Inspect, in most browsers). Tell me exactly what the finished HTML looks like, please - paste it here. And also what browser are you testing with? I think tiff is maybe supported only in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Another thing as well....any reason you can't just put `<img src="ImagesController/GetImageBytes/1" />` in your image tag directly? (Obviously, you'd have to put the required ID into your Model somewhere, instead of hard-coding, but you get the idea. Is there some reason you're need to do this in the backend instead of a direct request to the API?

Comment: Hi ADyson, sorry for delay, to reply to your previous comment , yes there is a team convection. But i have solved the issue, in my web api i have to return file content instead of string. I would like to thank you for your suggestion and support.